# Get numbers from string and convert to columns

Tags: sql-server

I have the following string in sql server where the length is variable

```
Test No [012345678] - Result Code/Desc [53015 / Ptq Last Test]
Test No [25688] - Result Code/Desc [123/ Testing Testing Last] 
Test No [456987] - Result Code/Desc [1234 / Last test test]
```

How could I select the test number '012345678', Result Code '53015' and Desc 'Ptq Last Test' in columns?? (the numbers and description have different length/size in my table) 
essentially the results should look like :

```
Test         Code   Desc
12345678     53015  Ptq Last Test
25688        123    Testing Testing Last
456987       1234   Last test test
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? have you have a look at `CHARINDEX`/`PATINDEX`?

Comment: `'Test No [25688] - Result Code/Desc [123 / Testing Testing Last]'` is the input for the second output entry or some thing else?

Comment: Also, you have 3 expected results, but only 1 input row? Where do the others come from?

Comment: I have updated the description for better understanding

Comment: You can use CHARINDEX to find the location of a substring, not just a single character.   Look at the difference between `CHARINDEX('No [', @string)` and `CHARINDEX('Desc [', @string)`.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps:

```
Declare @string Varchar(max) =  'Test No [012345678] - Result Code/Desc [53015 / Ptq Last Test]'
declare @secondPoint int = Charindex(' - ', @string)+1
declare @secodpart varchar(max) = Substring(@string, @secondPoint,LEN(@string) - @secondPoint)
declare @lastBlock varchar(max) = Substring(@secodpart, Charindex('[', @secodpart) + 1, LEN(@secodpart))

select 
substring(
    @string,
    Charindex('[', @string)+1
    ,Charindex(']', @string) - Charindex('[', @string) -1
    ) as [Test No]
    ,
RTRIM(LTRIM(substring(  @lastblock, 0 , CharIndex('/', @lastblock)))) as [Code],
RTRIM(LTRIM(substring(@lastblock, CharIndex(' / ', @lastblock)+3 , Len(@lastblock) - CharIndex('/', @lastblock)))) as [Desc]
```